# Why can't I iterate through a list of a Wrapper class in Salesforce Visualforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I am trying to iterate through a list of records inside a wrapper class and show them on a Visualforce page. The custom object is called Campaign_Products__c, and the wrapper class is meant to show if the product has been selected by the user to add to a "cart".

Apex Controller code (extraneous bits removed):

```
public with sharing class CONTROLLER_Store {
   ...
    public List<productOption> cpList           { get; set; }
    public class productOption {
        public Campaign_Product__c product;
        public Boolean inCart;
        public Integer quantity;
    }
   ...
    public CONTROLLER_Store(){
    ...
        List<Campaign> cmpList = getCampaignWithProducts(CampaignId,''); 
        // method above calls a campaign with a related list of Campaign Product records
        if(cmpList.size() > 0){
            cmp         = cmpList[0];
            cpList      = new List<productOption>();
            for(Campaign_Product__c pro : cmp.Campaign_Products__r){
                productOption option = new productOption();
                option.product  = pro;
                option.inCart   = false;
                option.quantity = 0;
                cpList.add(option);
            }
        } else {
            cmp         = new Campaign();
            CampaignId  = null;
            cpList      = new List<productOption>();
        }
    ....
    }
```

Visualforce page (extraneous bits removed)

```
<apex:page controller="CONTROLLER_Store" >
    <apex:repeat value="{! cpList }" var="option">
        {!option.product.Product__r.Name}    
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{! option.inCart }"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

I get this error when trying to save the visualforce page:

```
Unknown property 'CONTROLLER_Store.productOption.product'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the properties in your wrapper visible to VF too. Something like

```
public class productOption {
    public Campaign_Product__c product {get; private set};
    public Boolean inCart {get; set};
    public Integer quantity {get; set};
}
```

(assuming product should be readonly in VF). You need these access modifiers or full getter/setter methods.